# evaluate an assignment expression in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have an expression such as:

```
def expr = 'anything="something"'
```

In my case the above string comes from a web service, but it could be from anywhere.  I would like to evaluate this so that I end up with the variable "anything" that has a value of "something", such that:

```
assert anything=="something"
```

So far I tried:

```
def anything
Eval.me(expr)    // `anything` ends up null
```

From stuff I read on SO:

```
def anything
Eval.me(expr.inspect())    // same thing: `anything` ends up null
```

Also tried:

```
def anything
expr.execute()    // complains: "Executable name has embedded quote, split the arguments"
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [GroovyShell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy), take a look:

```
def expr = 'anything = "something"'

def binding = new Binding()
def groovyShell = new GroovyShell(binding)
groovyShell.evaluate(expr)

assert binding.getVariable('anything') == "something"
```

Comment: I slightly improved it by using `binding.getVariable(expr.split('=')[0])`. Works like a charm!

Comment: Nice, I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: Keep in mind that you are blindly executing any code that can be returned from that web service. I would be very wary of that. If you only get strings from that service, I would use a simple `.split('=')`, remove the quotes from the second value, and make the assignment myself.